# How to differentiate between quantum states based on phase

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-information, measurements, quantum-optics

Imagine you have a source of photons and a single-photon detector. The source emits photons that can be in any of the following four states: $ |1\rangle $, or $ -|1\rangle $, or $ i|1\rangle $, or $ -i|1\rangle $. Probabilities of all four states are equal.

If you can design an experiment and repeat it as many times as you want, what would you do to identify in which state each photon is? I guess there should be some way using phase difference. But how would you do it experimentally?

Comment: *"I guess there should be some way using phase difference. But how would you do it experimentally?"* Phase difference compared to *what*?

Comment: @dmckee Phase difference between photons in different states?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the axioms of quantum mechanics there is no way to measure the phase of a single state.

A subtle point that is often skipped over is that physical states do not correspond to vectors in a Hilbert space. Rather, if the vector $|\psi\rangle$ represents a particular state, then so does $z|\psi\rangle$, where $z$ is any complex number. Hence, there are an infinite number of Hilbert space vectors that represent exactly the same physical state. Specifically, it's impossible to measure the difference between $|1\rangle$ and $-i|1\rangle$ because those two vectors represent the same state.

The reason this should be is that the Born rule says that all measurable quantities involve taking absolute values of vectors. That is, the probability of finding ending in state $|B\rangle$ when you started in state $|A\rangle$ is
$$P =\frac{ \left|\langle B|A\rangle\right|^2}{\langle B| B\rangle \langle A| A\rangle}$$

You can see that changing $|A\rangle$ for $z |A\rangle$ leaves that quantity unchanged, and so that phase does not matter.

The trickiness comes in when we consider relative phase. $|1\rangle + |0\rangle$ does not represent the same state as $|1\rangle -i|0\rangle$ because you can't multiply the first vector by a single complex number to get the second one. We can in principle measure the difference between those two states.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. How would you go about differentiating experimentally between states that differ in relative phase? Let's say, $ |1\rangle + i|0\rangle $ compared to $ |1\rangle - i|0\rangle $?

Comment: @triclope Both states are orthogonal, so if you somehow put your photon in state $|1\rangle + i |0\rangle$ but in your experiment you only select $|1\rangle - i |0\rangle$ states you'll measure "nothing". This is the same as when you try to measure the horizontal component of vertically polarized light: there is none!